# Refresh recyclerView from inside ViewHolder's onLongClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a RecyclerView in my app using a custom adapter and viewholder.
The basic idea of what I want to implement is, that when you long click on an item it will show an AlertDialog that let's you add/remove the chosen item to/from a lost of favorite items. Any items that currently are marked as favoirte shall display a star drawble in the list. I do this by assinging a drawable to reserved view of the row iff it's a favorite in the onBindViewHolder method:

```
public class myAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<VerseAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<String> data;
FavoritesManager fav;
ArrayList<String> validFavs;

public myAdapter(List<String> vs, FavoritesManager favs) {
    fav = favs;
    data = vs;
    validFavs = fav.getFavorites();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // Inflate the custom layout
    View vsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

    // Return a new holder instance
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(vsView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    TextView txtVs = holder.vsText;
    View st = holder.star;
    if (validFavs.contains(data.get(position))){
        Drawable str = fav.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp);
        st.setBackground(str);
    }else{
        st.setBackground(null);
    }

    txtVs.setText(data.get(position));
}

[...]
}
```

I then have a onLongClickListener, that creates an AlertDialog, that let's you choose to change the favorite status of the selected item (this works. The favoriteManager does add/remove the correct item). But the RecyclerView doesn't update the star icon. I tried notifyDataSetChanged() and notifyItemChanged() but neither did work (actually, it makes kinda sense that it doesn't because technically the data did not change, but I want the adapter to handle the same data differently):

```
ublic class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView vsText;
    public View star;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        vsText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vs_txt);
        star = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.star_place);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            int selItem = 0;
            @Override

            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                boolean isFav = validFavs.contains( data.get(getAdapterPosition() +1));
                String dummy = "Add to favorites";
                final int pos = getAdapterPosition() +1;
                if (isFav) dummy = "Remove favorite";
                final CharSequence[] items = {dummy};

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Menu").setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dia, int sel){
                        selItem = sel;
                        System.out.println(pos);
                        String mark = "Added ";
                        if (validFavs.contains( data.get(pos))){
                            mark = "Removed ";
                            fav.removeFavorite(data.get(pos));
                        }else {
                            fav.addFavorite(data.get(pos));
                        }

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(fav.getContext(), mark + data.get(pos), 100);
                        toast.show();

                    }

                }).setCancelable(true);


                AlertDialog dialog  = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                notifyItemChanged(pos-1); // This does nothing
                return true;
            }

        });

    }
```

So I need some way to force the adapter from inside a onCLickListener of an AlertDialog in an onLongClickListener of the ViewHolder to refresh the view of the item in question. Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: `notifyItemChanged` should be inside `onClick` . That's when you are changing the status . And it should be `notifyItemChanged(pos)` not `notifyItemChanged(pos-1)` i think unless u r doing it deliberately I mean why are you using `getAdapterPosition() +1` ?

Comment: After ```fav.addFavourite(data.get(pos))``` try adding ```star.setBackground(...)```